# Python Script to extract data from Text to Excel/CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

Here I am trying to write a script in Python that would extract data from a **text file** into **CSV**.

The data looks like below:

```
*------------*
102GCPC-XP
not online
*------------*
------------
105PEACHPC


name                : 105PEACHPC
manufacturer        : Dell Inc.
model               : OptiPlex 755                 
totalphysicalmemory : 2101907456
domain              : abc.com

serialnumber : 90QZGG

version : 5.1.2600

Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R)

size : 79999073280

ipaddress : 255.255.0.0

------------
```

I want the data to look like below:

```
COMPUTER NAME | STATUS   | NAME     | MANUFACTURER | MODEL      | TOTALPHYSICALMEMORY | DOMAIN | SERIALNUMBER | VERSION | PROCESSOR         | SIZE      | IPADDRESS |
--------------+----------+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------+--------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
102GCPC-XP    |not online|          |              |            |                     |        |              |         |                   |           |           |
--------------+----------+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------+--------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
105PEACHPC    |Online    |105PEACHPC|Dell Inc.     |OptiPlex 755|2101907456           |abc.com |90QZGG        |5.1.2600 |Intel(R) Pentium(R)|79999073280|255.255.0.0|
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blocks appear to start and end with `----------`, with an extra `*` showing if the entry is online or not. The code first needs to split the text file into blocks by searching for this delimiter and then constructing an entry, line by line. When the end delimter is found it then uses a regular expression to find all matching `fieldnames`. Finally, a `csv.DictWriter()` is used to write the entries to a properly formatted CSV file that could be loaded into Excel:

```
import csv
import re

fieldnames = ['NAME', 'MANUFACTURER', 'MODEL', 'TOTALPHYSICALMEMORY', 
    'DOMAIN', 'SERIALNUMBER', 'VERSION', 'PROCESSOR', 'SIZE', 'IPADDRESS']

re_fields = re.compile(r'({})\s+:\s(.*)'.format('|'.join(fieldnames)), re.I)

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=['COMPUTER NAME', 'STATUS'] + fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()
    start = False

    for line in f_input:
        line = line.strip()

        if len(line): 
            if '------------' in line:
                if start:   
                    start = False
                    block.append(line)
                    text_block = '\n'.join(block)

                    for field, value in re_fields.findall(text_block):
                        entry[field.upper()] = value

                    if line[0] == '*':
                        entry['COMPUTER NAME'] = block[1]
                        entry['STATUS'] = block[2]
                    else:
                        entry['COMPUTER NAME'] = entry['NAME']
                        entry['STATUS'] = 'Online'

                    csv_output.writerow(entry)

                else:
                    start = True
                    entry = {}
                    block = [line]
            elif start:
                block.append(line)
```

So for the data you have provided, you would get `output.csv` containing:

```
COMPUTER NAME,STATUS,NAME,MANUFACTURER,MODEL,TOTALPHYSICALMEMORY,DOMAIN,SERIALNUMBER,VERSION,PROCESSOR,SIZE,IPADDRESS
102GCPC-XP,not online,,,,,,,,,,
105PEACHPC,Online,105PEACHPC,Dell Inc.,OptiPlex 755,2101907456,abc.com,90QZGG,5.1.2600,,79999073280,255.255.0.0
```

For Python 3.x use, modify the output code to:

```
open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
```

Comment: thanks for the script. I am trying to run the script and facing few errors. Can you please let me know version and ide tool you using to compile the script.

Comment: It is currently designed for Python 2.x but is easily adapted for Python 3.x

Comment: you have used "block" variable but I do not see it is defined any where?

Comment: It is defined inside the `else` statement  `block = [line]`. This bit of code is reached first as `start` is `False` to begin with.

Comment: Hello Martin, I was able to execute the code you provided and also get the result that I required. But now when I am trying to execute I dont get proper output. Though the excel sheet is created with column names but no data is appended.

Comment: I would need to see your actual input file to see what is going wrong. You could upload it to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and then paste the URL here to it as a comment.