# Python Script to extract multiple strings from text file

Tags: python, csv

i'm pretty new to using python and regex, looking for help setting up the basic structure of a python file to extract multiple strings from a text file.

The source of the data will always be a single text document, the output needs to be a CSV and
most important is to have all related data on a single row.

Each entry with in the text document will always start with "" and each entry will always end with "<>". Between  those two strings there will be multiple fields/strings, not every entry will have every field but if the entry exists there will be the preceding tag eg "Requesting Staff:" or "Class Name:" sometimes the data element will be on the same line as the tag, and sometimes it will be on the following line.

Here is an example section of the text document

```
DOCUMENT LIST                                                                                                                                  JUN 15,2022  10:14    PAGE 1
REPORT TEXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<NEW FILE>
<CustomerNAME> Demo,Test
<DOA>01/11/2002
<Account>3455
<DateofPurchase>JAN 4,2021@15:41:38
 Item Purchase Report 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Manager: 
 
Requesting Staff: 
  person, person 
 
Requested Item 
  Class Name: Truck
  Modle Name: tundra 
 
Indication for Lease: 
  work
 
Expected Duration of Lease: 
  3 years
 
Cost of Lease: 
   $2.682 
 
Availability of item : 
  In Current Stock 
 
Decision: 
  Approved 
 
Rationale for Approval: 
  no other option  
 
Comment: 
 
here is some sample text about the case 
sometimes there are multiple lines  
   
 
 
   <<END OF REPORT>>
<NEW FILE>
<CustomerNAME> Demo,person
<DOA>02/11/2001
<Account>3455
<DateofPurchase>JAN 4,2021@15:41:38
 Item Purchase Report 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Manager: name, name 
 
Requesting Staff: 
  Second, person 
 
Requested Item 
  Class Name: Sedan
  Modle Name: sebring 
 
Indication for Lease:  leisure
 
Expected Duration of Lease: 
  
 
Cost of Lease:    $2.682 
 
Availabilty of item : 

 
Decision: 
  Approved 
 
Rationale for Approval: 
  no other option  
 
Comment: 
 

   
 
 
   <<END OF REPORT>>
```

looking through other questions/answers i see the following [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890393/python-script-to-extract-data-from-text-to-excel-csv]
this is mostly what i'm looking for, but i'm too new at this to figure make it work for my data. any help adapting it to what i showed above would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want to extract lines of a text file and have them on the same line heres a way you can do it

remember to put file name in as a string

```
line = ""

with open("your_file_name") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        line = line + lines[i]
```

the variable line will now store all the lines in the txt file, you can use this to print or any way you want